# Show that $a_1 = 1$ and $a_{n +1}=\sqrt{2a_n}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I am trying to answer the following question:

Suppose the sequence is defined recursively by  $a_1 = 1$ and $a_{n +1}=\sqrt{2a_n},$ show that this sequence converges and determine its limit.

I was able to prove that the sequence is increasing and I know that $a_2 = 2^{1/2}, a_3 = 2^{3/4}, a_4 = 2^{7/8}$.... but it is not bounded above, so how can I prove that it  is convergent and how can I see the pattern in the $a_n's$?

Could someone help me please?

Comment: Is it suppose to say $a_1 = 1$?

Comment: Can you show that $$
a_n  = 2^{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} +  \cdots  + \frac{1}{{2^n }}} 
$$ (Hint: induction) and $$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left( {\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} +  \cdots  + \frac{1}{{2^n }}} \right) = 1\;?
$$ (Hint: geometric series)

Comment: Banach's fixed point on the interval $[1, 3]$.

Comment: @aahlback it is a previous exam question so I think yes it was a typo.

Comment: @Gary I think your formula for $a_n$ is not correct in case of $n=2$ .... right?

Comment: @Brain Sorry, it is the formula for $a_{n+1}$, $n\geq 1$.

Comment: @Gary do you mean that there are 2 inductions involved in solving this problem? one that Kavi said below and the other one for calculating the limit that you mentioned above? if so, what is the induction hypothesis  for proving your formula? will still $n\geq 1$ in it?

Comment: @Brain My approach is a separate one. You prove by induction, using the given recurrence formula that $$
a_n  = 2^{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} +  \cdots  + \frac{1}{{2^{n - 1} }}} 
$$ for any $n\geq 2$. Then as a second task, you prove that $$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left( {\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} +  \cdots  + \frac{1}{{2^{n - 1} }}} \right) = 1.
$$ This will show you that $a_n \to 2^1 =2$.

Comment: I think your approach answers the second part of the question and not the first part ..... right?

Comment: Apply Banach's fixed point theorem to the closed interval $[1,4]$.

Comment: @Brain No, it proves the convergence because that geometric series converges to $1$. We show that it converges by showing that the power of $2$ converges to $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prove by induction that $a_n \leq 2$ for all $n$. Use this to show that $a_{n+1} \geq a_n$. So $(a_n)$ is increasing and bounded above. Hence, $\lim a_n$ exists. If you call this limit $l$ then $l=\sqrt {2l}$ so $l=2$.

Comment: Perhaps it is also relevant to mention that every bounded monotonic sequence converges.

Comment: Also, since the limit exists, say $a_n\to a$, we can take in the recursive definition the limit on both sides and obtain either $a=0$ or $a=2$. Since $\left(a_n\right)_n$ is monotonic we must have $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=2$.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the induction, how will it work?

Comment: @Brain If $a_n \leq 2$ then $a_{n+1} \leq \sqrt {(2)(2)}=\sqrt 4=2$.